# scrapyrt not receiving response from scrapy crawler

Tags: curl, scrapy

I am trying to run scrapy crawler using **scrapyrt**. I get following response in browser

```
 {"status": "error", "message": "", "code": 500} response: 1
```

and this one in scrapyrt window

[image]

I have tried to edit the path of log file but it throws Permission denied error.

The crawler runs successfully (as it creates html file) but not receiving json response in **curl**.

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_PORT=>'9080',
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost/crawl.json?spider_name=dmoz&url=http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Ada/",
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,   
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,      
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT     => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,   
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,    
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,   
    CURLOPT_POST           => false
          ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) { echo "cURL Error #:" . $err; } 
    else { echo "response: ".$response; }
```

If the same crawler is executed from **scapy cmd** `scrapy crawl dmoz -a url="http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Ada/"`

the **output** is

`{'description': u'ACM Special Interest Group on Ada: information on SIGAda organization and pointers to current information and resources for the Ada programming language.',
 'name': u'SIGAda',
 'url': u'http://www.sigada.org/'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue:

Updated  "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scrapyrt\log.py" file with following.

Replaced

```
filename = settings.get('LOG_FILE')
```

with this

```
filename = "C:\\wamp64\\www\\dirbot-master\\logs\\dmoz\\log.log"
```

dirbot-master is scrapy project. 
Now I am receiving the response in browser.